# Writing algorithm for types of triangle

Tags: algorithm, geometry, logic, pseudocode

I am faced with a question that goes like this:

Write an algorithm that reads three integers `a, b, c` representing the sides of a triangle.
Next, print the type of triangle represented (scalene, equilateral, isosceles). 
Assume a valid triangle is represented.

I would like some feedback on the errors that my algorithm may present or what I can do to improve how sequential it is:

```
step 1)  Start
step 2)  Declare int a,b,c
step 3)  Prompt a,b,c
step 4)  Read a,b,c
step 5)  If (a<>b and b<>c and c<>a) then
step 6)  Print "Scalene Triangle"
step 7)  Elseif((a=b and a != c) or (a=c and a!=b) or (b=c and b!=a))
step 8)  Print "Isoceles Triangle"
step 9)  Elseif ((a=b & b!=c ) or (a=c & c!=b) or (b=c & c!=a)) then
step 10) Print "Equilateral Triangle"
step 11) Endif
step 12) Stop
```

Comment: Step 7) `else if ((a=b and a != c) or (a=c and a!=b) or (b=c and b!=a))`

Comment: I would check for most specialized first so check for Equilateral, if that fails check Isoceles then if that fails you must have a scalene.

Comment: Also be consistent with your use of `and` and `&`, they generally mean the same thing but they aren't always the same in terms of order of operations and that can come back to bite you.

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 types of Triangles

Consider A , B and C as 3 sides possible triangle then

1. Isosceles -> If (A equals B and not equals C) **OR** (B equals C and not equals A)
2. Scalene -> If A not equals B not equals C (All sides different)
3. Equilateral -> If A equals B equals C ( All sides equal)
4. Not a Triangle -> If sum of any two sides is less than equal to the thirds side 
   A + B less than equals C **OR**  C + A less than equals B **OR** C + B less than equals A

Answer (score 0):

You'll get equilateral triangle as an isoceles triangle too,so change it to:

- ...
- If ((a=b & b!=c ) or (a=c & c!=b) or (b=c & c!=a)) then
- Print "Scalene Triangle"
- ...